# Finding the level of recursion call in python

Tags: python

I have a function which is called recursively and I want to know the current level of recursion. Below code shows the method that I am using to calculate it, but it is not giving the expected results.

E.g. : To find the recursion level for a system path:

```
    import os
    funccount = 0

    def reccount(src):
        global funccount
        print "Function level of %s is %d" %(src, funccount)

    def runrec(src):
        global funccount
        funccount = funccount + 1
        lists = os.listdir(src)
        if((len(lists) == 0)):
            funccount = funccount - 1
        reccount(src)
        for x in lists:
             srcname = os.path.join(src, x)
             if((len(lists) - 1) == lists.index(x)):
                  if (not(os.path.isdir(srcname))):
                       funccount = funccount - 1
             if os.path.isdir(srcname):
                runrec(srcname)

    runrec(C:\test)
```

Problem : Given a directory path, print the level of recursion for directory

Directory Structure is :
In my directory structure, i will call the function "reccount(Test)" (Function will be called with path to MainFolder). I want to know the level of recursion call for each folder. (Directory only)

```
Test:
   |----------doc
   |----------share
                |----------doc
                            |----------file1
   |----------bin
                |----------common
                             |----------doc
   |----------extras
   |----------file2
```

When i call the procedure, i get the following result:

```
    Function level of C:\test is 1
    Function level of C:\test\bin is 2
    Function level of C:\test\bin\common is 3
    Function level of C:\test\bin\common\doc is 3
    Function level of C:\test\doc is 3
    Function level of C:\test\extras is 3
    Function level of C:\test\share is 4
    Function level of C:\test\share\doc is 5
```

As you can see, when it prints results for bin/common/doc, it prints 3 instead of 4 and all subsequent results are wrong

Comment: I think the title should be "Specifying a level of recursion in a function". I found this looking for "finding the level of recursion of the function" (without modifying the function). Something like the deep of the stack trace, in order to detect deep calls.

Comment: The most straightforward / least-effort solution is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115298/how-do-i-get-the-current-depth-of-the-python-interpreter-stack — use `len(inspect.stack(0))` after `import inspect`. (There's also another answer on that question that is faster, but if speed is an issue then manually passing the depth around should be even faster.)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
def some_method(data, level=0):


    some_method(..., level=level+1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_method(my_data)
```

Comment: Does it work with variable number of arguments?

Answer (score 36):

```
from inspect import getouterframes, currentframe
import os

def runrec(src):
    level = len(getouterframes(currentframe(1)))
    print("Function level of {} is {}".format(src, level))
    for x in os.listdir(src):
        srcname = os.path.join(src, x)
        if os.path.isdir(srcname):
            runrec(srcname)

runrec('C:\\test')
```

---

```
Function level of C:\test is 1
Function level of C:\test\bin is 2
Function level of C:\test\bin\common is 3
Function level of C:\test\bin\common\doc is 4
Function level of C:\test\doc is 2
Function level of C:\test\extras is 2
Function level of C:\test\share is 2
Function level of C:\test\share\doc is 3
```

Comment: Although Andreas's answer is the obvious choice for the OP, +1 for a solution that doesn't require the extra parameter. Extremely useful for printing nested debug info from a recursive function without the hassle of the extra param.

Comment: if you call this function from another function, the numbers will increase, while recursion depth will remain the same, and parameter based approach lacks this flaw.

Comment: Just a question.. how is the use of getouterframes and currenteframe different from using inspect.stack() ?

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you store the recursion level in a parameter?

```
def runrec(src, level=1):
  # ...
  runrec(new_src, level + 1)
```

That way, you don't need a global variable:

```
def reccount(src, level):
    print "Function count of {} is {}".format(src, level)
```