# Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow error using Selenium and ChromeDriverManager

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

My code worked fine until a few days ago. But now I'm facing an error as follows:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow
```

with the minimal code:

[image: my code]

Error:

[image: errors screen]

What's the cause of the sudden errors?

Comment: Can you add the full code in `textual` format ?

Comment: and if it worked, we will need your actual code, not web driver settings, because the error is about stackoverflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and text based complete error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

[image: Cannot recover from stack overflow]

...indicates that [ChromeDriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742262/7429447) is initiating multiple threads while trying to download the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and is reaching the limit of the interpreter stack during that infinite recursive *`loop`*.

---

### This usecase

I don't see any significant error in your code block as I was able to execute similar lines of code on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) box perfecto:

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
  driver.get('https://pypi.org/')
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  ====== WebDriver manager ======
  Current google-chrome version is 110.0.5481
  Get LATEST chromedriver version for 110.0.5481 google-chrome
  Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/110.0.5481.77/chromedriver_win32.zip
  Driver has been saved in cache [C:\Users\debanjan.bhattacharj\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\110.0.5481.77]
  ```

---

### Solution

As a preventive measure you can:

- Upgrading [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73199422/7429447)
- Reinstall [WebDriver manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447)
- Reinstall [*Selenium-Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269228/7429447)

---

### References

A few helpful documentations:

- [Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4391)
- [How do I get the current depth of the Python interpreter stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115298/7429447)
- [Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50508591/7429447)