# How can I get current depth of the Ruby interpreter stack?

Tags: ruby, stack

I want to get stack depth, to know how deep it go in recursive function.

I found [How do I get the current depth of the Python interpreter stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115298/how-do-i-get-the-current-depth-of-the-python-interpreter-stack) this, and this is what exactly I want, but it's python, and I couldn't find anything like this when I googled 'Ruby get stack depth'.

What I want to do is something like this:

```rb
def recursive_func(n)
   if n == 1
      return get_current_depth()
   end
   recursive_func(n - 1)
end
```

What can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably like this using [`caller`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller):

```
caller.length
```

Keep in mind that starts at a certain depth when your program spins up, so you may want to subtract that from your count.