How to watch recursion depth in vscode?
I'm trying to convert a custom json-like response structure to json object. Since lists can contain dicts and vice versa, I'm calling them recursively as they appear. While the recursion is deep, I don't think it should have exceeded the recursion depth. So, I think I have a bug in the handling. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the way that vs code is counting recursion and it's actually running out of recursion and I should increase it.
So, I would like to keep a watch on the recursion depth as I step through and try to get a sense of where I'm growing the recursion when I should be returning. However, I don't see a variable I can watch in VS code to see the recursion depth. Please help

Do the answers to this question help at all?

There's no variable for recursion depth. What you're looking for is a view of the call stack.

can you not see a call stack in the debug view?

@quamrana Thanks! the lower ranked answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115488/1304376 had what I needed. I think the error message made me look for recursion depth instead of stack depth. So watching len(inspect.stack(0)) was what I needed
